# "В то время(,) как..."

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли тут расставлены знаки препинания: "...огромные деньги были потрачены на этот чемпионат в то время, как многим людям в стране не хватает средств на то, чтобы оплатить коммунальные услуги"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Составной подчинительный союз *в то время как* может расчленяться в зависимости от интонации.
*..огромные деньги были потрачены на этот чемпионат в то время, как многим людям в стране не хватает средств на то, чтобы оплатить коммунальные услуги"* или *..огромные деньги были потрачены на этот чемпионат, в то время как многим людям в стране не хватает средств на то, чтобы оплатить коммунальные услуги"*